# How can I refresh the browser using JSP scriptlet code?

Tags: java, jsp, scriptlet

So, I am doing something like the following:

```
// do something in JSP1
// load HTML page in JSP1
// send post request via jquery in JSP1 to JSP2
// do some processing in JSP2
// set "request" object from JSP2 to JSP1 by using:
request.setAttribute("results",returneddocs);
rd.forward(request, response);
// Now, I am able to read the new values in JSP1 by using:
myval = request.getAttribute("results");
```

Now, I want to use the value of "myval" to make certain divs appear or disappear. How do I do this? 
Maybe I can set "session" instead of "request" and refresh the HTML page. But how do I refresh the HTML page using code in the jsp scriplet?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have received value(s) in `myval`, there is no need to refresh the whole page. As, you can control rendering of your html using simple CSS.

> I want to use the value of "myval" to make certain divs appear or
>   disappear. How do I do this?

First parse value to specific data-type, don't forget to check null and empty.

```
String myval = (String) request.getAttribute("results");
```

Lets say your `myval` contains `show` as value, then add style to div(s) as following, based on the value, what you have got in it:

```
<% String display = myval.equals("show") ? "block" : "none"; %>
<div style="display=<%=display %>"></div>
```

> Maybe I can set "session" instead of "request" and refresh the HTML
>   page.

Reloading page will cost twice call to server.

> But how do I refresh the HTML page using code in the jsp scriplet?

No need to refresh the whole page, this should do the needful. But, if you have hard-n-fast need to refresh the page, you can do as following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var value = '<%=myval %>';
    if(value == "some value")
        location.reload();
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Coz once the page is loaded, it does not take the updated values.

Comment: So you need to set value on each page load.

Comment: Which i why i want to set "session" and then reload the page.

Comment: And when will your reloading stop? Wouldn't this create an infinite loop of reload each time you receive a new value.

Comment: When you are redirecting back to jsp1 after setting request attribute, wouldn't it will be the updated one?

Comment: No. I want to only reload when he the value of the JSP variable changes.

Comment: Changes in a sense, what sort of value do you have in variable?

Comment: Basically they are search results of a query. I am now using ajax to get json from the server. It's all working well. :)